# Can I make TextBlock clickable - Based on XML parsing results?

Tags: xml, silverlight, linq, windows-phone-7

I have a stack panel with multiple text blocks which are bound to parsed results from an XML file.

What I would like to is to make each results have an onlick event which would then link to more information or even a message.show box, but it must use a value from the results it displays.

This is the .Xaml section for the listbox which disaplys the results.)

```
<ListBox Height="435"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Name="TradeSearch1"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="397"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
         Margin="0,63,0,0">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Height="200">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                   Height="150" Width="150"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Margin="0,10,8,0"/>
            <StackPanel Width="370" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Foreground="#FFE51A1A"
                           FontSize="16" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PriceDisplay}" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           FontSize="20" 
                           Foreground="Black" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ListingId}" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           FontSize="20" 
                           Foreground="Black" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Region}" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                           FontSize="18" 
                           Foreground="Black" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

One of the text blocks returns a value for (ListingID). ideally when a user clicks this result they they will be taken to another page which will disaply more results based on the LIstingID form that results.

Listing ID is 400332970

Is there any way to carry that value to another page and use it in something like this? Where ListingID.XMl would be the listingId from the onClick result.

```
WebClient Trademe = new WebClient();
Trademe.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Trademe_DownloadStringCompleted);
Trademe.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Listings/" + ListingID.xml));
```

I am sorry if this is confusing, I have tried to explain as best I can. Hopefully someone has an idea of what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you could use a [QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to pass the information along to the next page.

```
//handle the selectionchanged event (replace 'myObject' with your object type)
void ListBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as myObject);
    if(lbi != null)
    {
        string id = lbi.ListingId.ToString();
        NavigationService.Navigate("/NewPage.xaml?listingid=" + id, UriKind.Relative));    
    }
}
```

Then, in your `NewPage.xaml` page, you can read the value of the query string. (You can add error checks, or use `QueryString.TryGetValue` instead to avoid exceptions).

```
string id = NavigationContext.QueryString["listingid"];
```

You can use `id` as part of the download code you posted.

Comment: wouldn't that pass all the listingID's? Rather than the one the the user clicks on ? There are around 20 different listings all with thier own ListingID

Comment: @Rhys: No it wouldn't. Presumably you tie the ListBox's ItemSource to some collection in code behind. The `myObject` mentioned in the answer above is an object from that collection. So the object corresponding to the selected item of the ListBox will contained only the listing ID of the ListBoxItem that was tapped.

Comment: @keyboardP Ok, sounds like a solution for me then. I dont understand replaceing my object with object type? Do you mean String, Bool etc.?

Comment: What's the name of the class that has `Title`, `PriceDisplay`, `ListingId` and `Region`? That will be the object type in this case, so replace `myObject` with the name of that class.

Comment: Ah I get it.. Thanks again for your help. Your a legend!! :)

Comment: @keyboardP I have spent a few hours on this now and can't get it to work. Perhaps I didn't word it correctly.

Comment: @keyboardP Still not working. I am getting multiple errors around the ListBoxSelectionChangeMethod around not having two arguments.

Comment: also `string id = NavigationContext.QueryString["listingid"];` is giving the error `Object reference is required for non static fields, method or property System.Windows.Navigation.Context.QueryString.Get` and `NavigationService.Navigate("/NewPage.xaml?listingid=" + id, UriKind.Relative));` is throwing an error was it suppose to have new uri("/NewPage....`